# Cambiar de idioma a los modal de permisos del sistema en iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

No han aceptado mi aplicación en la App Store porque el idioma principal de mi app es el español, pero mis modal que solicitan permisos, si el dispositivo está en ingles, se ponen de este idioma. Los de apple me dicen que toda mi aplicación debe estar en español sin importar el idioma del dispositivo.

He buscado la forma de solucionarlo, pero ni una forma me ayudó.

Ya cambié el lenguaje de desarrollo a español y aun así sigue saliendo en ingles. No se con qué mas intentar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna solución para esto? D:

Answer (score 2):

No puedes cambiar el idioma de este modal. Refiérete a [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353736/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-dialog-message-when-asking-for-notification-perm).

Lo que te recomiendo hacer es un diálogo personalizado en español, el cual mostrarías antes de presentar el diálogo por defecto del sistema. El contenido de esta alerta personalizada sería algo como "Smiledu requiere de tu permiso para enviar notificaciones...", o como mejor veas apropiado (podría ser explicando por qué tu app requiere el permiso en primer lugar).

El diálogo podría simplemente ser uno súper básico con un OK como acción de cierre. Posteriormente mostrarías el diálogo por defecto del sistema para que el usuario otorgue los permisos.

Aquí te dejo un fragmento de código como ejemplo:

```
let customAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Smiledu", message: "Smiledu requiere de tu permiso para enviar notificaciones, y así mejorar tu experiencia al usar nuestra app!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let okAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {
    (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    //muestras el diálogo por defecto del sistema
})
customAlertController.addAction(okAlertAction)
self.present(customAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```